# PHP password form

Tags: php, forms

when I run this php script, it echos out an error of '0' at the bottom. When I put the correct name and password, it puts me through to the correct page. Equally when I put the wrong user and password, the correct message appears. Why is there that an initial '0'?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <meta charset ="utf-8">
            <title>Login page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Log in to our Website here:</h1>

    <?php 
    $self = htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    $creds = array(
                array('username' => 'Bob',
                        'password' => 'bill'),
                array('username' => 'mary',
                        'password' => 'jane')
                );
    $match = false;
    $errors = $username = $password = 0;
    if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $details_entered = true;
        $username = trim($_POST['username']);
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);
            for ($i=0; $i<count($creds); $i++) {
                if(strcmp($username, $creds[$i]['username']) ==0) {
                    if(strcmp($password, $creds[$i]['password']) ==0) {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['authenticated'] = true;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $creds[$i]['username'];
                $match = true; 
            } 
        } else {
            $errors = "***Either your username or password are not correct***";
        }
    }
}

if($match) {
    header ('location: login.php');
}
?>

        <form id = "login" action ="<?php echo $self; ?>" method ="post">
        <fieldset>

        <p>
        <label for ="username">*UserName:</label>
        <input type ="text" name ="username" id ="username" maxlength ="50" placeholder ="Username"/>
        </p>

        <p>
        <label for = "password">*Password:</label>
        <input type ="password" name ="password" id="password" maxlength ="50" placeholder ="Password"/>
        </p><span><?php echo $errors; ?></span>

        <p>
        <input type ="submit" name ="Login" value ="Login"/>
        </p>

        <p>
        <a href = "register.html">Or register with us here:</a>
        </p>

        </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: `Why is there that an initial '0'?` because `$errors = $username = $password = 0;`

Comment: As @Lashane points out, you're not checking for the form submission on the initial page load, so you get an output you're not expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `$errors = $username = $password = 0;` to `$errors = $username = $password = "";` This should fix the problem.

Comment: What would *really* fix the problem is checking for form submission. And some other stuff.

Comment: @jay-blanchard, this code has many problems but this is not a theme of this question.

Comment: If this answer is fix you problem please mark answer as good. Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

You declared your $errors variable with an initial value of '0'. It's not necessary and it's what causes the problem.